# My script run in ISE but got an error in console

Tags: powershell, windows-7, powershell-2.0

My script **run in the ISE** but when i want to run it in cmd or with the right click on my script file and run with `Powershell` I have an error message.
I'm on **Windows 7** and my Powershell version is **Powershell 2.0**

Already tried execute

```
powershell.exe -STA -FILE "C:\Users\Mgtspare\Documents\Conversion\Conversion_Script.ps1"
```

**My script:**

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\Users\Mgtspare\Downloads"
$watcher.Filter = "*.xls"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
$action = { 
            $watcher.Path *.xls | rename-item -newname { [io.path]::ChangeExtension($_.name, "xlsx") }
          }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

**Error message:**

> You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '*' operator.

[image]

Comment: `$watcher.Path *.xls` is invalid.  Maybe you meant to just pipe the property into the command `$watcher.Path | rename-item .....`

Comment: I found the solution $watcher.Path was the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

$watcher.Path was the problem of my script, i changed my script you can see below the solution if someone need it :

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\Users\Mgtspare\Downloads"
    #$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { 
                Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Mgtspare\Downloads *.xls | rename-item -newname { [io.path]::ChangeExtension($_.name, "xlsx") }
              }

### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher 'Created' -SourceIdentifier 'FileCreated' -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```